# How to disallow heroku rake db:drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a whole bunch of projects in the same folder and I frequently run the command "heroku rake db:drop" when I'm working on new projects.  My nightmare is that I will run the command on the wrong project one day.  Even though I have daily backups it would be horrible to lose many hours of data.

Is it possible to somehow disallow certain commands for specific projects?  For example, I'd like to completely disallow the following commands on our live projects if possible -

heroku rake db:drop

heroku rake db:migrate VERSION=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in the Heroku gem.

Maybe you could monkey patch it locally to suit your needs? https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/run.rb

Comment: is it possible to disallow it on the command line/bash itself?  because i do actually want to use that command on certain projects but just not on live ones.